# how to get text before the starting of specific html tag using html dom parser PHP

Tags: html, tags

I'm unable to figure out to get text between html tags. in my scenario required text is not wrapped between tags except paragraph tag `<p>`.

```
<div class="entry clearfix">
<p>111</p>
<p><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-38376" src="1.jpg" alt="Talvar" /></p>
<p><strong>111: </strong>111<br/>
    <strong>111:</strong> 111<br/>
    <strong>111:</strong> 111 111<br/>
    <strong>111: </strong>111<br/>
    <strong>111: </strong>1111
</p>
<p><strong>111</strong></p>
<p>
    <strong>01 &#8211;</strong> data1 <strong><a href="#">Download</a><br/>
    </strong><em>222</em><br/>
    <strong>02 &#8211;</strong> data2 <strong><a href="#">Download</a><br/>
    </strong><em>222</em><br/>
    <strong>03 &#8211;</strong> data3 <strong><a href="#">Download</a><br/>
    </strong><em>222</em><br/>
    <strong>04 &#8211;</strong> data4 <strong><a href="#">Download</a><br/>
    </strong><em>222</em>
</p>
<p><strong>222</strong></p>
<p><strong><a href="" target="_blank">3333</a></strong></p>
<p><strong>eb</strong></p></div>
```

i need data1, data2, data3, data4. for that i am finding `<p>` which is number 5 as in array number 4.

```
    foreach($html->find('div[class="entry"]') as $row){
        $a = $row->find('p',4);
        echo $dt = $a->find('text',1)->plaintext; // returns me only data1
    }
```

data1, data2, data3, data4 are not between any tags except `<p>` if i get them through `striptags()` it returns all texts along with 111, Download, 222 etc. please advise how i can get data series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about more elegant ways, but this should work too:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class="entry"]') as $row){
$a = $row->find('p',4);

$str=$a->find('strong');
$em=$a->find('em');

foreach($str as $tag) {

$a=str_replace($tag,'',$a);
$a=str_replace($em,'',$a);


        }

}

echo strip_tags($a,'<br>'); // if you want to keep br tags
```

So, idea is - remove `strong` and `em` tags (and text content inside, including links), inside targeted `p`, with `str_replace`, and get the rest. 
If your HTML structure is like this one you've posted, it should work.

Comment: thank you for answering, implemented your method but situation is same as i mentioned above about `strip_tags()`. after doing str_replace rest structure remains as  to solve. `<p>` having unmanaged `data` serial  that can't assign to an array. although during replacing stuff after getting combined data i exploded it and converted into an array. i believe there would be better method for this. well thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can easily get array: $str=strip_tags($a,'<br>');  print_r(explode('<br/>',$str)); However, if you find better, method, let us know. :)